# deploy ScheduledExecutorService on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, scheduledexecutorservice

I've been using the Beeper Control example that is all around to make this work. It does work, but I need to integrate this to a Tomcat server. I know I have to use a listener and add it to web.xml file, but any step-by-step tutorial around? or can anyone give me the steps to deploy it?

thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link to it?